# Can we edit this question into shape?`

Tags: discussion, specific-question

[How to handle it when you didn't do ANYTHING](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/q/71369/16)

I know that in its current form it does not meet our standards but the core of the question here should be on topic and we should be able to edit the question into a form that we can help.  I also think it calls for a more politic hand than mine.

Answer (score 6):

My personal thoughts: I looked this over a fair bit and am not really sure that it can be. The core question is, basically, either:

- How do I handle feeling upset when I am not able to do my academic/work obligations together as well as I feel like I should?

or, perhaps the real core question:

- What should I be doing in order to finish my masters thesis while working fulltime and finding it hard to get "into" it?

The first *could* be edited but it would still be borderline, I think. The second could be something like "how can I balance fulltime work and pursuing a masters?" but I'm not sure that would really be the core question.

I *think* there is a strong theme of dealing with depression in this, too, which I'm not sure what to make of but I do know it'd make it harder to really get the question the OP is wanting to answer to actually get meaningful, actionable actions.

Comment: I guess I was thinking something along the lines of how can i set myself up for the best chance to move forward.  But I suspect you are right the entire dealing with depression part probably needs to be removed to be on topic which kind of defeats the purpose of the question for the OP

Answer (score -4):

I don't think so.

The question is very broad and includes a fair amount of whining.

I'm even entirely sure what the OP is asking.